# Editing DataGridView data changes row orders

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` (`dgvVolReport`) bound to a `DataTable`. There is a column in the table called `"group"` (`colGroup` on the `DataGridView`). I am trying to create a button that can group together (i.e. assign the same group number to) all selected rows.

I have the logic of assigning the group numbers and editing the other group number correct and the new groups for each row are stored in a `List<int>` called `groupNumbersAll`.

I then transfer these number to the `DataGridView` like so:

```
for (int r = 0; r < groupNumbersAll.Count; r++)
{
    dgvVolReport.Rows[r].Cells["colGroup"].Value = groupNumbersAll[r];
}

// A breakpoint is set on this line (i.e. values below are BEFORE this line has been run
dgvVolReport.Sort(colGroup, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

And somehow that seems to change the row orders or assign the numbers to the wrong rows.

I have debugged just after that loop and the contents of `groupNumbersAll` is correct:

[image]

Note that those two pinned "sixes" correspond to the two selected rows (they were fives before). Now here is what the contents of the `colGroup` column look like:

[image]

You can see that from row `6` they don't match. Why don't they match? WHY?

But more bizarrely, if I comment out the last line (`dgvVolReport.Sort(colGroup, ListSortDirection.Ascending);`), which has not even run yet since that's where the breakpoint lies, then suddenly they do match!!! Does anyone know what's going on here?

btw I have also tried unbinding and then rebinding the DataSource which I thought worked for a time but now I see that it does not.

The following is the complete code (from a button click) for the group button as requested (Note that the final working code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799185/1011724)):

```
private void btnGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //dgvVolReport.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

            List<int> groupNumbersAll = new List<int>();
            List<int> groupNumbersNotSelected = new List<int>();
            List<int> groupNumbersSelected = new List<int>();
            List<int> rowNumbersSelected = new List<int>();
            List<int> groupNumbersOfEntirelySelectedGroups = new List<int>();

            // Populate groups (All, Selected and NotSelected)
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvVolReport.Rows)
            {
                groupNumbersAll.Add(Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["colGroup"].Value));

                if (row.Selected)
                {
                    groupNumbersSelected.Add(Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["colGroup"].Value));
                    rowNumbersSelected.Add(row.Index);
                }
                else
                {
                    groupNumbersNotSelected.Add(Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["colGroup"].Value));
                }
            }

            int smallestSelectedGroupNumber = groupNumbersSelected.Min();
            int newGroupNumber = smallestSelectedGroupNumber;
            bool newGroupFlag = false;
            // If the selected rows do not contain all rows with group number equal to the smallest selected group number,
            // then we need to create a new group whose group number is the smallest selected group number plus 1.
            // This then implies that we need to add 1 to the group number of every row with a group number larger than the
            // lowest selected group number (that is the original lowest selected number before we added 1).
            if (groupNumbersNotSelected.Contains(smallestSelectedGroupNumber))
            {
                newGroupNumber++;
                newGroupFlag = true;
            }

            // Find which groups have been selected entirely, but ignore the smallest number. 
            // If a group has been entirely selected it means that that group number will no longer exist. Thus we will have to 
            // subtract 1 from each group number that is larger than a group that has been entirely selected. This process is 
            // cumulative, so if a number is higher than 2 entirely selected groups (excluding the smallest selected group) then
            // we need to subtract 2 from the group number.
            foreach (int group in groupNumbersSelected.Distinct())
            {
                if (!groupNumbersNotSelected.Contains(group) && !(group == smallestSelectedGroupNumber))
                {
                    groupNumbersOfEntirelySelectedGroups.Add(group);
                }
            }

            // Find the new group numbers
            for (int r = 0; r < groupNumbersAll.Count; r++)
            {
                int groupNum = groupNumbersAll[r];

                if (rowNumbersSelected.Contains(r))
                {
                    groupNumbersAll[r] = newGroupNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    int subtract = groupNumbersOfEntirelySelectedGroups.Where(num => num < groupNum).Count();

                    if (newGroupFlag && groupNum >= newGroupNumber)
                    {
                        groupNum++;
                    }

                    groupNumbersAll[r] = groupNum - subtract;
                }
            }

            //// Unbind the data table because of weird ass sorting error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785736/editing-datagridview-data-changes-row-orders/30799185#30799185
            //DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvVolReport.DataSource;

            //dgvVolReport.DataSource = null;
            ////Alter the values on the underlying DataTable
            //for (int r = 0; r < groupNumbersAll.Count; r++)
            //{
            //    dt.Rows[r]["Group"] = groupNumbersAll[r];
            //}
            ////Rebind
            //dgvVolReport.DataSource = dt;

            //((DataView)dgvVolReport.DataSource).Sort = null;

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvVolReport.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["colGroup"].Value = groupNumbersAll[counter++];
            }

            dgvVolReport.Sort(colGroup, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, that's the same code that I'm using? The group numbers are not row numbers.

Comment: I suspect it is something to do with the sorting that you're doing. Is colGroup involved in the sorting at all? If you're sorting at the wrong time then your indexes would go out of sync.

Comment: I call sort on the line that the breakpoint is currently set at. Does sort get automatically called every time a value changes? Maybe I just need to turn that off...

Comment: So I've tried turning the `SortMode` for that column to `.Programmatic` before the loop and abck to `.Automatic` afterwards and that does fix it. However if I comment out this line (which occurs after the loop and also AFTER the point at which I am breaking and inspecting the values shown above): `dgvVolReport.Sort(colGroup, ListSortDirection.Ascending);` then suddenly it works. **So the presence of that line later in the code alters the behaviour before it occurs!!!** How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `groupNumbersAll` - or how it is used - is to blame.  It is hard to be certain because we can't see how it is used and more importantly, prepared for reuse.  This however, is incorrect:

```
for (int r = 0; r < groupNumbersAll.Count; r++)
{
    dgvVolReport.Rows[r].Cells["colGroup"].Value = groupNumbersAll[r];
}
```

If the DGV is databound, you should not be changing values in the DGV.  In fact, if you query a cell after a new assignment, you should see that it is unchanged:

```
Console.WriteLine(dgvGrouper.Rows[1].Cells[GrpColIndex].Value);
dgvGrouper.Rows[1].Cells[GrpColIndex].Value = 99;
Console.WriteLine(dgvGrouper.Rows[1].Cells[GrpColIndex].Value);
```

Mine prints the same value before as after.  I have to think that the Group value doesn't show on the grid or  you would see that the value is not changing.  Instead you should be changing the DataSource:

```
for (int n = 0; n < myDT.Rows.Count; n++)
{
    myDT.Rows[n][GrpColIndex] = rList[n];
}
```

My data looks like this:
[image]

The Name and Value both represent the original data order.

The problem is that sorting changes the display order, but not the underlying `DataTable` - the DGV is simply presenting a View of the data (DataTable -> DataView -> DataGridView control).  Dumping the Group values for a sorted DGV, List and DataTable demonstrates this:

```
*** SORTED DGV Rows to List and DT  ***
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 1   DT Val: 1  
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 2   DT Val: 2  
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 2   DT Val: 2  
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 1   DT Val: 1  
DGV Grp: 2   List Val: 1   DT Val: 1  
DGV Grp: 2   List Val: 1   DT Val: 1
```

I grouped rows 2 and 3 thru the DataTable.  Afterwards the List and DT are in synch, but the DGV is not. The next time you iterate the DGV for the selected rows those row indices have no relation to the List index or DataTable row index.

Since the DGV selected rows is the starting point, you need to convert a `DataGridView` selected row index to a `DataTable` row index.  If other things can happen to the DGV (rows added, rows deleted, user sort by column etc), I'd rebuild the List every time (I'd do this anyway since it is so utterly detached from the control and the data):

```
// rebuild the List from the Group value in the DataTable
rList = new List<int>();
for (Int32 n = 0; n < myDT.Rows.Count; n++)
{
   rList.Add((int)myDT.Rows[n][GrpColIndex]);
}

// loop thru the selected rows
foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in dgvGrouper.SelectedRows)
{
   // get at the underlying data item for this row
   // which is likely at a different index than the DGV row
   DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)dgvr.DataBoundItem;

   // use the DataView.Table to get the index of this DataRowView
   rList[dr.DataView.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr.Row)] = newGrpVal;
}
newGrpVal += 1;
```

`dr.DataView.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr.Row)` basically converts the DGV visual selected row index to the actual `DataTable` row index.  As long as the group values don't have intrinsic meaning, you might be able to use something simple like the counter shown.  If you need the current value of the selected rows from the table for a more robust group method `dr[GrpColIndex]` should contain the value you need.

Example:
Baker and Charlie have already been regrouped.  The DGV shows them at the bottom, but we saw that they remain in slots 2 and 3 in the `DataTable`.  Now, after selecting Delta and Echo, the above code runs. View of the indices before changes are applied:

```
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 1   DT Val: 1
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 2   DT Val: 2
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 2   DT Val: 2
DGV Grp: 1   List Val: 3   DT Val: 1
DGV Grp: 2   List Val: 3   DT Val: 1
DGV Grp: 2   List Val: 1   DT Val: 1
```

The planned changes are spot on; items 4 and 5 will be set as group #3 and sort to the bottom.  Just copy the list to the data source:

```
for (int n = 0; n < myDT.Rows.Count; n++)
{
   myDT.Rows[n][GrpColIndex] = rList[n];
}
```

[image]

It would be nice if something like a Dictionary or Tuple, perhaps using the hashcode from a row could tie things together better, but I cant work out anything which works better than restarting the list.

I'll try to amend with any salient information as time allows once more information about the list and/or grouping is available.

Comment: I'll post more code on Monday. But I have to reassign the group's that are higher than those selected as they could go up if a new group is created or down if multiple group's are merged.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  But if the list isnt reloaded the next time, its starting point wont match the current order for the DGV rows.

Comment: I'll post the code on monday (although the grouping logic is kind of convoluted), I'm sure it has to do with the gridview sorting differently from the datatable, but I can't work it out. More to come when I'm back at work.

Comment: I've added the full code now. I think though that what you are saying with the `DataView` and your examples do sound like a correct solution to the problem and I will try them out now

Comment: Thanks - looks to be working now! I'm going to add the full working code to my old answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30799185/1011724) on the off chance anyone wants to see it

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Plutonix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30944009/1011724), this is the final working code:

```
        private void btnGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785736/editing-datagridview-data-changes-row-orders

            List<int> groupNumbersAll = new List<int>();
            List<int> groupNumbersNotSelected = new List<int>();
            List<int> groupNumbersSelected = new List<int>();
            List<int> rowNumbersSelected = new List<int>();
            List<int> groupNumbersOfEntirelySelectedGroups = new List<int>();

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvVolReport.DataSource;

            // Populate groups (All, Selected and NotSelected)
            for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
            {
                int group = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[r]["Group"]);
                groupNumbersAll.Add(group);

                bool selected = false;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow gridrow in dgvVolReport.SelectedRows)
                {
                    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)gridrow.DataBoundItem;
                    selected |= dr.DataView.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr.Row) == r;
                }

                if (selected)
                {
                    groupNumbersSelected.Add(group);
                    rowNumbersSelected.Add(r);
                }
                else
                {
                    groupNumbersNotSelected.Add(group);
                }
            }

            int smallestSelectedGroupNumber = groupNumbersSelected.Min();
            int newGroupNumber = smallestSelectedGroupNumber;
            bool newGroupFlag = false;
            // If the selected rows do not contain all rows with group number equal to the smallest selected group number,
            // then we need to create a new group whose group number is the smallest selected group number plus 1.
            // This then implies that we need to add 1 to the group number of every row with a group number larger than the
            // lowest selected group number (that is the original lowest selected number before we added 1).
            if (groupNumbersNotSelected.Contains(smallestSelectedGroupNumber))
            {
                newGroupNumber++;
                newGroupFlag = true;
            }

            // Find which groups have been selected entirely, but ignore the smallest number. 
            // If a group has been entirely selected it means that that group number will no longer exist. Thus we will have to 
            // subtract 1 from each group number that is larger than a group that has been entirely selected. This process is 
            // cumulative, so if a number is higher than 2 entirely selected groups (excluding the smallest selected group) then
            // we need to subtract 2 from the group number.
            foreach (int group in groupNumbersSelected.Distinct())
            {
                if (!groupNumbersNotSelected.Contains(group) && !(group == smallestSelectedGroupNumber))
                {
                    groupNumbersOfEntirelySelectedGroups.Add(group);
                }
            }

            // Find the new group numbers
            for (int r = 0; r < groupNumbersAll.Count; r++)
            {
                int groupNum = groupNumbersAll[r];

                if (rowNumbersSelected.Contains(r))
                {
                    groupNumbersAll[r] = newGroupNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    int subtract = groupNumbersOfEntirelySelectedGroups.Where(num => num < groupNum).Count();

                    if (newGroupFlag && groupNum >= newGroupNumber)
                    {
                        groupNum++;
                    }

                    groupNumbersAll[r] = groupNum - subtract;
                }
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < dt.Rows.Count; n++)
            {
                dt.Rows[n]["Group"] = groupNumbersAll[n];
            }   

            dgvVolReport.Sort(colGroup, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the value has not yet committed to the underlying data source

To modify the underlying data source directly

```
for (int r = 0; r < groupNumbersAll.Count; r++)
{
    var drv = (DataRowView)dgvVolReport.Rows[r].DataBoundItem;
    drv.Row["colGroup"] = groupNumbersAll[r];
}
```

Comment: Nope, gives the same incorrect behaviour. (again only if I have that `sort` line *later* in the code)

Answer (score 0):

I would also try editing the `DataTable` directly. Skip using the `groupNumbersAll` for now and use an incremental value for testing, instead:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvVolReport.DataSource;
dgvVolReport.DataSource = null;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    dt.Rows[i]["Group"] = i;
}

dgvVolReport.DataSource = dt;
//dgvVolReport.Sort(colGroup, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

If each row and column `"Group"` in the `DataGridView` doesn't display an unique integer, the problem is in the `DataGridView`'s properties. You should also check the `"Group"`-column's properties (value type etc).